# Catalog page product not showing in magento 2.1.3

Tags: product, error, catalog, magento-2.1.3, reindex

After running the code "

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

" my catalog products are not showing in front end also i have get an error like this in command prompt "

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Locale' not found in
>   /var/www/html/m2/v
>   endor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php:64"

Comment: Could you please check PHP intl  extension is installed or not ?

Comment: Also, do you have any additional modules active?

Comment: @ Manthan Dave how can i check it i have installed the magento before 4 moths and at that time i think i installed it and every thing working fine yesterday i faced a problem my newly registered customers are not see on back end so i tried to re-inexing it after running the re-index command my catalog products also gone

Comment: On server side, run `php -i | grep 'intl'`. If it returns empty it means you didn't install PHP intl extension before.

Comment: @ PY Yick its show like this it means the intl is not installed  ?
  root@Magento2:/var/www/html/m2# php -i | grep 'intl'
  root@Magento2:/var/www/html/m2#